# complex dataframe filtering request on the last occurence of a value in Panda/Python [EDIT]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a hard time to do a complex dataframe filtering.

Here the problem:

For each column 'id' of same value, the column 'job' can take the values 'fireman','nan','policeman'.

I would like to filter my dataframe so that for each id of same value,

I keep only the rows starting where the value 'fireman' for job is occuring the last consecutive time. I first have to group by 'job' values to filter on:

```
 df.groupby("job").filter(lambda x: f(x))
```

I don't know which function f is appropriate.

Any ideas ?

To try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[79,1,], [79,2,'fireman'],[79,3,'fireman'],[79,4,],[79,5,],[79,6,'fireman'],[79,7,'fireman'],[79,8,'policeman']], columns=['id','day','job'])


output = pd.DataFrame([[79,6,'fireman'],[79,7,'fireman'],[79,8,'policeman']], columns=['id','day','job'])
```

Comment: If you want to aggregate the dataframe based on the `imo` (for each column 'imo' of same value...) why do you want to group by `polygon`?

Comment: Maybe you right then I have to group by `imo` and filter on polygon ?

Comment: Can you add why you need this type of filtering. Its bit tough

Comment: thovex its still unclear how to approach the problem. Can you add few more examples

Comment: I need this because each imo is a boat and each row is where it is located (polygon) and I need to know the last time it comes to the 'FE' area and leaves it

Comment: whats the output  if Australia is first and FE is last in last three rows of DF. Please add details like this in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version without the need of extra variables:

```
df.groupby('imo').apply(lambda grp: grp[grp.index >= 
                                        ((grp.polygon.shift() != grp.polygon) & 
                                         (grp.polygon.shift(-1) == grp.polygon) & 
                                         (grp.polygon == 'FE')
                                        ).cumsum().idxmax()]
                       ).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks it's much faster than the last version !